# Подключение по OpenVPN в Windows и монтирование сетевых дисков с сервера

Tags: windows, cmd, openvpn, share

Всем привет. Который день бьюсь над этой проблемой. Есть OpenVPN сервер у меня под Linux. Есть домен. Есть шары. Раздал пользователям флешки на которых OpenVPN Portable, устанавливать ее не надо для удобства, но запускать надо от имени администратора. В конфиге подключения:

```
script-security 3 system
route-up "start.cmd"
down "unmount.cmd"
```

То есть что-бы запустить скрипт, надо поднять права пользователя.
Скрипт запускается, сетевые диски монтируются, но монтируются они администратору, а не пользователю который инициировал подключение.

Есть идеи как это исправить?

**Обновление**

Он запускает другой скрипт, так как сразу монтирование не работает:

```
start mount.cmd. mount.cmd: net use * /delete /yes
net use * "\\172.16.0.1\Home$\" PASSWORD /user:"USERNAME" /persistent:yes
```

Comment: Можно содержимое start.cmd?

Answer (score 1):

Подтверждаю актуальность проблемы. OpenVPN GUI для Windows с целью поднятия интерфейса и добавления маршрутов требует поднятия прав, в итоге указанный в конфиге скрипт монтирования дисков выполняется с правами администратора.

Внятного и аккуратного решения, похоже, не существует.

Придумал только костыльное решение, через журналы событий.

1. В конфиге подключения указываем путь до скрипта:

   ```
   up 'c:\\Windows\\system32\\wscript.exe c:\\Program\ Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\up.vbs'
   ```
2. В скрипте `up.vbs` создаём запись в журнале событий c ID, равным 777 (можно выбрать любой другой ID на своё усмотрение):

   ```
   Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Command = "eventcreate /T Information /ID 777 /L Application /D " & Chr(34) & "VPN-соединение установлено." & Chr(34)
   WshShell.Run Command,0,false
   ```

   При подключении OpenVPN в журнал событий `Приложение` будет добавлено событие от `EventCreate` с ID = 777.
3. В планировщике задач создаём задачу, выполняемую для зарегистрированного пользователя, без повышения прав.

   На вкладке `Триггеры` указываем:

   - начало задачи `При событии`
   - журнал `Application`
   - код события `777`

   На вкладке `Действия` указываем путь до скрипта монтирования дисков.

---

Можно сделать и проще. Конечно, если не смущают мигающие окна командной строки. Для этого можно воспользоваться [фичей OpenVPN GUI для запуска скриптов](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn-gui/#run-connectdisconnectpreconnect-scripts). Вместо п.п. 1-2 положить в папку `config` файл `xxxx_up.cmd` (где `хххх` - имя OpenVPN-соединения) примерно того же содержания:

```
    eventcreate /T Information /ID 777 /L Application /D "VPN-соединение установлено."
```

Тогда в конфиге вообще не надо ссылаться на скрипт. При установлении соединения на долю секунды появится чёрное окно командной строки, и событие будет добавлено в журнал приложений, после чего отработает планировщик задач и подмонтирует диски.

Описанный выше способ, может, и кривоват, но зато вполне нормально работает в продакшене. На время установления соединения особо не влияет. Пользователи ничего не замечают.

При желании можно создать свой отдельный журнал и писать события в него, но этот перфекционизм уже выходит за рамки решения проблемы.

Размонтирование дисков производится аналогичным способом.

Comment: К сожалению имя пользователя динамическое. То есть я не могу у всех прописать в планировщик данное решение.